# Cut long strings into something shorter

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 24

void rez(char **c, char *s, int n, int ks);

void rez(char **c, char *s, int n, int ks)
{
    int t = 0, j = 0;
    char *p;
    p = strtok(s," ");
    t = t + strlen(p);
    if (strlen(p)>N) *(c+j)=(char*)malloc((strlen(p)+1)*sizeof(char));
    else *(c+j)=(char*)malloc((N+1)*sizeof(char));
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        if (t>N)
        {  
            *(*(c+j)+t) = '\0';
            t = strlen(p) + 1;
            j++; 
            if (t>N) *(c+j)=(char*)malloc(strlen(p)+1);
            else *(c+j)=(char*)malloc(N+1);
        }
        strcat(*(c+j), p);
        c[j][t]=' ';
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        t=t+strlen(p)+1;
    }
    c[j][t]='\0';
    for(j=0; j<ks; j++)
    {
        printf("\n  %s", *(c+j));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fin;
    int n, ks;
    char s1[2048], filename[256];
    char **c;

    printf("Enter the file name->");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    fin=fopen(filename,"r");
    if (!fin)
    {
       printf ("Error\n");
       return -1;
    }
    while (fscanf(fin, "%[^\n]", s1)==1)
    {
        fscanf(fin, "%*[ \n]");
        printf("\n String:   %s \n", s1);
        n=strlen(s1);
        ks=n/(N-1)+1;
        c=(char **)malloc(ks*sizeof(char*));
        rez(c, s1, n, ks);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

This code should cut long strings into some shorter, but it gives "core dumped" in gcc. It doesn't exit from while in `void rez()`.

In my mind, `strtok()` works incorrectly.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Step 1, for me, would be renaming all those one-character variable names to something useful. (And Step 2, of course, would be to use a debugger.)

Comment: Also step 3, change all the nasty pointer dereferencing to simple and readable array notation, e.g. `*(*(c+j)+t)=' ';` -> `c[j][t] = ' ';`.

Comment: And step 4, get rid of the redundant stuff, like casts on the result of malloc, and multiplying by `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: `fscanf(fin, "%[ \n]", g);` --> `fscanf(fin, "%*[ \n]");`

Comment: Nothing has changed, the problem isn't solved

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
char r[1]=" ";
```

because the string literal `" "` is TWO characters!  It is both a space and a NULL-terminator (which is at the end of every string in C.  But you explicitly said it should only be a 1 character array.

Comment: Correct it to TWO, but it doesn't help